# Insert image from ActiveDirectory to SPListItem c#

Tags: development, active-directory, splistitem

First of all, I would like to ask question, do I need to insert image to Sharepoint as `Image` or `byte[]` array?

I have tried both ways to do that. In both cases it returns me `System.ArgumentNullException`. And there is not additional information, that I could make use of.

```
    SPUser user = web.EnsureUser(account);
    SPListItem item = items.Items.GetItemById(user.ID);

    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
    for (int i = 1; i < _propKeys.Length / 2; i++)
    {
       string val = person.Data.Where(a => a.Key == _propKeys[i, 0]).Select(a => a.Value).FirstOrDefault();

        if (_propKeys[i, 1] == "Image" && val != null)
        {
            item[_propKeys[i, 1]] = GetUserImage(acc);
        }
        else
            item[_propKeys[i, 1]] = val;

        item.Update();
     }
     web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
```

To convert item to Image I have tried to use following code:

```
public static Image GetUserImage(string userName)
        {
            var directoryEntry = Values.enTry;
            var directorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry);
            directorySearcher.Filter = string.Format("(&(SAMAccountName={0}))", userName);
            var user = directorySearcher.FindOne();

            var bytes = user.Properties["thumbnailPhoto"][0] as byte[];
            // I tried this byte array as well, got `NullReference` from there


            Image returnImage;
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
            {
                returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
            }
            return returnImage;
        }
```

I have hear, that I can't actually insert image straight to Sharepoint list, but I need to create library and from there take Image URL and insert that to list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, got the solution for my problem. First of all, I needed to use image URL to insert it into list.

First of all, i got Image bytes from Active Directory:

```
        public static string GetUserImage(string userName)
        {
            var directoryEntry = Values.enTry;
            var directorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry);
            directorySearcher.Filter = string.Format("(&(SAMAccountName={0}))", userName);
            var user = directorySearcher.FindOne();

            byte[] bytes = (byte[])user.Properties["thumbnailPhoto"][0] as byte[];

            return UploadImage(userName, bytes);
        }
```

Then I used these bytes to add Image as file and to insert into Sharepoint Library, that I made:

```
public static string UploadImage(string userName, byte[] img)
        {
            string loc = String.Empty;
            using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(Values.SiteUrl))
            {
                using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPFolder myLibrary = oWeb.Folders["Profile"];

                    // Prepare to upload
                    Boolean replaceExistingFiles = true;

                    // Upload document
                    SPFile spfile = myLibrary.Files.Add(userName + ".jpg", img, replaceExistingFiles);
                    loc = (string) spfile.Item[SPBuiltInFieldId.EncodedAbsUrl];

                    // Commit 
                    myLibrary.Update();
                }
            }
            return loc;
        }
```

In the end I returned file location (full URL) and inserted that to list! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to upload an image (a file in general) to SharePoint you can send it either as [stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468469/how-do-you-upload-a-file-to-a-document-library-in-sharepoint) or as [byte array](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2010/07/04/programatically-upload-a-document-in-sharepoint-2010-document-library/). Personally I prefer the latter one.

Instead of

```
var bytes = user.Properties["thumbnailPhoto"][0] as byte[];
```

try

```
byte[] bytes = (byte[])user.Properties["thumbnailPhoto"].Value;
```

See a similar solution with code samples [here](https://pholpar.wordpress.com/2010/08/10/synchronizing-user-image-between-active-directory-and-sharepoint-profile/).

Comment: There is not property `Value`. And your link is broken, I think. Also could you tell, if I need to send Image or bytes to Sharepoint?

Comment: The object 'user' must be an instance of the type 'DirectoryEntry'. It has a 'Properties' collection, via the indexer can one a single property (that is a 'PropertyValueCollection' type). The type 'PropertyValueCollection' should have a 'Value' property of type 'object'. Please note, that there is no extra integer indexer in my code (that is, not user.Properties["thumbnailPhoto"][0].Value)!